# How to query by relationship and?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a grails domain class `Character`

```
class Character {

    String name
    int level
    boolean alive
    Player player

    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false, unique:true)
        level(min:1)
        player(nullable:false)
    }
}
```

I want to query for a character with a specified player, where the value of alive is "true".  I tried using the following, but it

```
Character.findByPlayerAndAliveEqual(p, true)
```

But it generates an exception

```
No signature of method: static java.lang.Character.findByPlayerAndAliveEqual() is applicable for argument types: (com.thestreetsgame.security.Player, java.lang.Boolean) values: [com.thestreetsgame.security.Player : 1, true]
```

I've also tried `findByPlayerAndAlive`, with the same result.  How can I make this gorm query work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oops**, the important part of the exception just jumped out at me.

```
java.lang.Character
```

I was trying to do a lookup on the core java class instead of my domain class.  Need to always use the fully qualified name, or change the name of the class.

For the time being I've fully qualified the reference, and it is working.